# I get the following error when trying to run my application. There are no errors in the source code

Tags: iphone

I get the following error when trying to run my application. There are no errors in the source code.

```
                      Undefined symbols:
  "__Block_object_dispose", referenced from:
      ___destroy_helper_block_2 in myprojectAppDelegate.o
      ___destroy_helper_block_1 in myprojectAppDelegate.o

  "__NSConcreteStackBlock", referenced from:
      __NSConcreteStackBlock$non_lazy_ptr in myprojectAppDelegate.o
     (maybe you meant: __NSConcreteStackBlock$non_lazy_ptr)

  "__Block_object_assign", referenced from:
      ___copy_helper_block_2 in myprojectAppDelegate.o
      ___copy_helper_block_1 in myprojectAppDelegate.o

ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the Xcode version. The project was built in Xcode version4.2 and I was trying to run it on Xcode3.2. Later I updated the Xcode and changed the sdk to the latest one it started working..

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some things.  Maybe another source file you didn't include?  Look at the methods "destroy_helper_block_1" and see what's being called there that you don't have.  It could be that some case is wrong, or that you are calling a framework that you haven't included.  Your linker is trying to put everything together, but your source code is calling for things that aren't there.

Comment: I'd rather suspect a missing framework instead of a source file (the latter would have caused a compile error).

Comment: Could be a missing include library as well.  A compile error doesn't always happen because Obj-C will let you call a method that doesn't exist (at least, Xcode defaults to that as a warning).  The above sometimes happens when people add a new file to a source controlled project, but only add it to the project and forget to check it into source control.